# Python, how can I import modules that are in sub-directory?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Python and Flask to build a project.

How can I import modules that are in sub-directory?

here is the directory structure.

```
/application
  /apis
    settings.py
index.py
```

and here is the index.py file.

```
from flask import Flask
import os
import sys
import random
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, send_file, Response, make_response
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

sys.path.append("apis")
import settings
```

here is the settings.py file in apis folder.

```
from flask import Flask
import pymongo
import datetime
import os
import sys
import random
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, send_file, Response, make_response
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

## About Us
@app.route('/apis/settings/aboutus')
def aboutus():
    return render_template('aboutus.html')
```

So, I tried to import settings module by using sys.path.append.

When all codes was in index.py, it worked fine.

If I hit this address http://domain.com:5000/apis/settings/aboutus, it supposed to show AboutUS page.

However, it says "404 Not Found" after I split modules.

Can you see the problem?

Comment: You need to use [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks, I checked bludprints. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a "package". Basically a directory that contains `__init__.py`.

usually you can (*naively*) do something like this:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/__init__.py
```

"foo" must be in the `sys.path` however.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that flask support this kind of problem.

Larger Applications
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/

I checked this page, and it describes how to import python modules.

Thank you!